# validation on field name add with for with jquery Validation

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-plugins

I have a form built dynamically by php script with a for/loop:

```
<form id="formDay">
    {loop="$elenco"}
        <input type="text" name="day[{$value.day}][date]">
    {/loop}
</form>
```

This form I try to validate in this way

```
$('#formDay').validate({
    rules: {
        "input[name^='day']": {
            required: true,
            date: true
         }
    }
});
```

but doesn't work because it can not find the fields that beginning with "day".
Is it possibile to resolve this problem with this plugin (http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation)?

UPDATE 1:
Sorry, I was my mistake: I wanted to write "day" and not "giornata" ;)

Comment: It doesn't appear that any of the inputs' names start with "giornata". I don't see what the issue is.

Comment: Try `input:not([name=giornata])`.

Comment: My mistake: I wanted to write "day" and not "giornata"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you just can just add the classes "required date" in your php code.
The validation plugin can also work that way!

```
<form id="formDay">
    {loop="$elenco"}
        <input type="text" class="required date" name="day[{$value.day}][date]">
    {/loop}
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input[name^=test]").each(function() {
    test1 = $(this).attr('name');
    console.log(test1);
});
```